# What happens if I increment a value in a 16-bit register that has already maximum value?( Assembly 8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've placed the value of BX register to `FFFF` and I did the command `inc BX`, The value turned into `0000`. Where did the value go? I checked the flags but I still couldn't come up with an explanation.

Comment: `0xFFFF + 1 = 0x10000` and you are storing the result into 16 bit register, so it gets truncated to `0x0000` ... Just like when you do `mov bx,0x8000` `add bx,0x8000` -> `bx == 0x0000` too. Flags reflect the situation according to the definition in Intel manual (`add` will set all flags, `inc` preserves carry flag, in this case of zero result both will set ZF=1, but only `add` will modify CF=1). Not sure if you are asking about the missing CF update by `inc`, or if you are missing the nature of 16 bit arithmetic and why the result is truncated?

Answer (score 1):

0xFFFF + 1 = 0x10000 and you are storing the result into 16 bit register, so it gets truncated to 0x0000 (the result would need at least 17 bits to avoid truncation).

Just like when you do `mov bx,0x8000` `add bx,0x8000` -> bx == 0x0000 too.

Flags reflect the situation according to the definition in Intel manual,  `add` will set all flags accordingly, `inc` preserves carry flag and modifies all other flags.

In this case of zero result both will set ZF=1, but only `add` will modify CF=1.

This inconsistency between `add/adc x,1` vs `inc x` and `sub/sbb x,1` vs `dec x` is intentional design by Intel engineers to allow for simple creation of loops where the two instructions work in tandem, `inc/dec` not disrupting the chain of `adc/sbb` instructions, like addition of arbitrary long integers stored in memory:

```
  ; 16 bit x86 real mode code, will do "destination += source;"
  ; ds:si = source integer, ds:di = destination integer
  ; cx = length in words of integers (bytes = 2*cx)
  ; modifies all involved registers and ax
  clc      ; clear carry flag to not affect result of addition
add_loop:
  lodsw    ; ax = another word of source integer, si+=2
  adc  [di], ax    ; destination_word += source_word + carry
  ; this did also set new carry for next word, so it must be preserved
  lea  di,[di+2]   ; advance also di by 2, with LEA to preserve carry
  dec  cx          ; test if all word have been processed (preserves carry)
  jnz  add_loop    ; but zero flag is being set by the `dec` = loop condition
  ret      ; here the long integers addition is done
```

Comment: `ADC` makes use and changes the carry, not `ADD`, right? Also the fact that it goes to zero or changes flags is not specific to INTEL processors. Many processors have such features.

Comment: @Alexis, on x68, ADD and ADC both set the flags. ADC adds the carry into the sum, while ADD does not.

Comment: @Alexis, Many processors have such features, but the details may vary depending on the type of processor, so for a precise answer it is important to know the processor in question.